# Duplicate primary key when inserting using EF5

Tags: entity-framework

When I am trying to insert some value using this code I am getting the error below:

> {"ORA-00001: unique constraint (NCOREDB.PK_NCORE_CASH_IN) violated"}

I am using EF5 and Oracle as Database.It was working fine a while ago. I can not update my EF because of some dependency issue.

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {

                NCORE_TRN_CASH_IN_INFO OBJ_NCORE_TRN_CASH_IN_INFO = new NCORE_TRN_CASH_IN_INFO();

                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Obj_nCoreEntities.NCORE_TRN_CASH_IN_INFO.Max(t => (int?)t.CASH_IN_ID)) + 1;
                    OBJ_NCORE_TRN_CASH_IN_INFO.CASH_IN_ID = id;

//Inserting other value here

    Obj_nCoreEntities.NCORE_TRN_CASH_IN_INFO.Add(OBJ_NCORE_TRN_CASH_IN_INFO);
                    Obj_nCoreEntities.SaveChanges();

                    transactionScope.Complete();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                transactionScope.Dispose();
                string inner = ExceptionExtendedMethods.GetDBInnerExceptions(dbEx);                   
                return inner;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transactionScope.Dispose();
                string inner4 = ExceptionExtendedMethods.GetInnerExceptions(ex);
                return inner4;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Off-topic: I always find it inconceivable that people keep using the illegible class and property names their ORM seems to generate. It's virtually impossible to read the code. On-topic: looks like a concurrency issue.

Comment: `CASH_IN_ID` should be backed by an identity column and should not be set explicitly in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I can't add CASH_IN_ID as an identity column because in oracle 12c I can not add identity to an existing column.@phuzi

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.